# Flutter - Translate oninit

Tags: flutter, internationalization

Class 1

```
@override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        text =DemoLocalizations.of(context).trans('connection');
      }
```

Class 2 (DemoLocalizations)

```
 Future<bool> load() async {

    String data = await rootBundle.loadString('locale/i18n_${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> _result = json.decode(data);

    this._sentences = new Map();
    _result.forEach((String key, dynamic value) {
      this._sentences[key] = value.toString();
    });

    return true;
  }
```

Return

[image]

So the question is: How can i load custom string (internazionalization) when screen load (oninit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `didChangeDependencies` instead of `initState`.
It is called once after widget creation and again when the state of DemoLocalizations is changed.